# How to set default connection parameters for DBLINK on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have Postgresql 9.5 installed on Ubuntu and need to use dblink.  However I am using port 5433 (set in postgresql.conf) but dblink always defaults to port 5432.  I know you can specify the port in the dblink parameters, but this is massive redundancy when I want to use the default port of my instance.

There is a way of telling dblink to use a specific port by default.  I know this because I have successfully changed it in the past - but can't for the life of me remember how I did it.  I have tried setting the PGPORT environment variable and rebooting.  I have tried recreating the extension.  I have tried reinstalling postgresql-contrib.  None of this has made a difference.  I have a feeling that there is some obscure file I edited but can't remember what, where or how.

Any suggestions of how to change the default connection parameters for dblink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

It IS done by changing the environment variable, but this is not an environment variable in the sense that a Windows user would understand it (so changing /etc/environment does not work and neither does any other normal nix-style setting of global environment variables).

To change the default connection parameters for dblink you need to add PGPORT=5433 (in my case) to /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/environment.  The annoying thing with Ubuntu install of Postgres is that I have at least three versions of all these sorts of files (including pg_HBA.conf and so on).  The ones in /etc/... are mostly not read apart from in this case.  It's the ones in my data directory (which for space reasons is in a non-default location).  So, for anybody else having the same issue check /etc, /var, /your-data-directory.